# Converting an iterative function to a recursive function without changing parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I want to convert the iterative template function getSmallest into a recursive function without changing anything in main (no changing function parameters etc.) because in class we are being taught to always keep the public interfaces of our functions the same (so if we work in a big project, we don't start changing things that break the whole program)

Here's the program I wish to convert:

```
// PRE: 0 <= start < end <= length of arr
// PARAM: arr = array of integers
//        start = start index of sub-array
//        end = end index of sub-array + 1
// POST: returns index of smallest value in arr{start:end}

template <class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    int smallest = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

I have spent the last few hours scouring class notes, the internet and stackoverflow for any help but it all seems not related to my problem, so I am asking here.

Here is the best attempt I came up with:

```
template <class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end)
{
    int smallest = 0; //this should only run on the first recursion, not the rest
    i = start;
        if (i == end-1)
        {
            return smallest;
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[smallest])
            {
                smallest = i;
            }
            return getSmallest<T>(arr, i, end);
        }
    
}
```

I can't seem to make `int smallest = 0;` only run on the first recursion and while my program compiles, it is functionally useless.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. A recursive function would have a signature like `int getSmallest(Iterator start, Iterator end, T currentmin)`. You can implement this recursive function and have a function with the old signature call it internally.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that makes sense, no wonder it felt like i was hitting a wall constantly. Thank you!

Comment: @EOF A recursive solution is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67714491/2410359) without function signature change.

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 Recursive `getSmallest()` is amiss.  Perhaps you wanted `if (i == end-0)`?  (it still has other troubles too.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ok: "A recursive solution that has the same behavior (O(1) memory use [requires tail call elimination, which is not guaranteed by C], O(n) runtime) is not possible without a signature change". Happy now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three conditions:

1. The array has no elements.
2. The array has 1 element.
3. The array has more than 1 element

The first condition we can return `-1`, for the second condition we return the index of the first element, and for the third condition we compare the current minimum with the minimum element found from the rest of the array, and return the index of the smallest:

```
template<class T>
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (end - start == 0)
    return -1;
  if (end - start == 1)
    return start;
  int idx = getSmallest(arr, start + 1, end);
  if (arr[start] < arr[idx])
    return start;
  return idx;
}
```

Comment: Very similar to how im learning at the moment too, it really keeps it basic and helps, thanks!

Comment: could you explain maybe how it works? im trying to understand WHY this works and i cant quite wrap my head around it

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 Let's say the array is `a={3}`. `getSmallest(a, 0, 1)` will return the index of `3` which is `0`. With `a={3,2}`, we consider the first element to be the minimum so far, so we have to search the rest of the array for the smallest, and then compare to the first. That's what `getSmallest(a, start+1, end)` does. You'll notice that since there's only one element left in the rest of the array, it returns the index of that last element, so `idx=1`. Then `arr[start] < arr[idx]` is used to find the minimum of the two (which is `2` at index `1`). (cont.)

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 (cont) Let's say the array is `a={3,2,1}`. We consider the first element the smallest so far and search the rest of the array. From the previous example we know what `getSmallest()` will do on a 2-element array. It will return `2`, which is the index of `1`. Then we compare `arr[start]` (which is `3`) with `arr[idx]` (which is `1`). This will hold for an array of any size.

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 Recusion can be confusing, but a trick that I learned is to not think of the function call as a recursive call. Just imagine that it's a regular function call that will return the correct answer. So `int idx = getSmallest(arr, start + 1, end)` will return the index of the smallest element, and then we use `idx` to compare it to the first element - the thought of it being recursive shouldn't come to mind.

Comment: Thats actually a really good way of looking at it, ill definitely use that trick, thank you so much for all your explanation and work!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a recursive function of **depth** O(N) (as in OP's attempt), how about a recursive function of depth O(log(N))?

Divide the array in 2 each recursion.

```
int getSmallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (start + 1 == end) {
    return start; 
  }
  int mid = start + (end-start)/2; // mid = (start + end)/2 may overflow
  int left = getSmallest(arr, start, mid + 1);
  int right = getSmallest(arr, mid, end); 
  return arr[left] < arr[right] ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: You only get `O(log(N))` if you assume the data is pre-ordered (sorted). In which case, you can as well offer a `O(1)` function, which simply returns the first element. If the data is not pre-ordered, your function is just as O(N) as the original, as you need to look into both halves of the array (all N values). And if you think of depth of stack, it all depends on if your compiler has tail call optimization and if you use the correct optimization flags.

Comment: @BitTickler We are talking about 2 different things.  This code has **recursive depth** of O(log(N)) even if not optimized, unlike other answers with worth case depth of O(n).  The **run time** is O(n).  The answer does not claim that the run time is O(log(N)).

Comment: i just ran it and it had trouble sorting the 9 in an array length 10 (numbers 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9), BUT it worked perfectly fine for strings and also for the int's, every nnumber except 9 was ordered. Thanks!

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 The "end = end index of sub-array + 1" was read wrong by me.  Code adjusted.

Answer (score -1):

The general way to transform an iterative function is to replace each loop with a helper function. For example:

```cpp
for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
        smallest = i;
    }
}
```

We first rewrite this into a `while` loop:

```cpp
int i = start + 1;
while (i < end) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[smallest) {
        smallest = i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

We then ask ourselves "what variables defined before the loop do we use in the loop?" Answer: `arr`, `i`, `end`, and `smallest`. These become the inputs of our function.

We then ask ourselves: what state was modified in the loop that we later use outside the loop? Answer: the value of `smallest`. This becomes our output.

We thus write the following helper function:

```cpp
int helper_function(int i, int end, T arr[], int smallest) {
    if (i < end) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
        i = i + 1;
        return helper_function(i, end, arr, smallest);
    } else {
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

which can be rewritten to

```cpp
int helper_function(int i, int end, T arr[], int smallest) {
    return i < end ? helper_function(i + 1, 
                                     end, 
                                     arr, 
                                     arr[i] < arr[smallest] ? i : smallest)
                   : smallest;
}
```

And replace the loop with

```cpp
smallest = helper_function(i, end, arr, smallest);
```

So the code at this stage is

```cpp
int helper_function(int i, int end, T arr[], int smallest) {
    return i < end ? helper_function(i + 1, 
                                     end, 
                                     arr, 
                                     arr[i] < arr[smallest] ? i : smallest)
                   : smallest;
}

int get_smallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    int smallest = start;
    int i = start + 1;
    smallest = helper_function(i, end, arr, smallest);
    return smallest;
}
```

And of course we can dramatically simplify `get_smallest` - we don't need to redefine `smallest` and then return it, for example. So we get the following code for `get_smallest`:

```cpp
int get_smallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    return helper_function(start + 1, end, arr, start);
}
```

What do you do if there's more than one level of loop nesting? Get rid of the loops one at a time starting from the outermost loop.

Note that in this special case, it's possible to solve the problem with a different recursive algorithm. That algorithm would look like this:

```cpp
int get_smallest(T arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (start + 1 < end) {
        int result = get_smallest(arr, start + 1, end);
        return arr[result] < arr[start] ? result : start;
    } else {
        return start;
    }
}
```

This is possible because of the fact that the `min` function is associative.

Comment: This was super informative, thanks!!! tbh it was a way more thorough explanation then any lab instructor ever gave :)

Comment: @GuardedGauntlet447 I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score -1):

Before there were lambda functions in C++ (c++11 and newer has them), there was no other way than creating helper functions with an extra argument for the state (e.g. the accumulator or the smallest value or whatever is wanted). Other languages including old and dusty Pascal have nested functions.

```
template <class T>
T smallest(const T* first, const T* last) {
  // iterative implementation
}
```

turns, with the help of lambda functions into:

```
template <class T>
T smallest(const T* first, const T* last) {
  T result = 0; // dubious in itself, because we do not want to assume too much about what T actually is.
  auto loop = [&result,last] (const T* current) {
     if (current < last) {
        if (*current < result) {
           result = *current;
        }
        loop(current + 1);
     }
  };
  loop(first);
  return result; 
}
```

Because the implementation is only really and truly generic if we do not assume too much about `T`, the line `T result = 0;` is already too much and we would need some generic 0 for every conceivable type. And even this would be wrong, because if we have an array containing negative numbers, you would need the smallest possible value and not 0 for the whole thing to work correctly.
What we also silently assumed is that there is an `operator<(T x, T y)` defined for T and that it is the one we want (imagine we want to use it for `T = std::string` - case sensitive comparison? utf8 aware? case insensitive?).

So, even though changing interfaces in code is often not a good idea, sometimes there simply should be an improvement. Because, lets admit it - the design of this function is bad, because it tries to sell us more genericity than it can truly grant.

```
template <class T>
T* smallest(const T* first, const T* last) {
  if (first == last)
     return last;
  auto loop = [] (const T* first, const T* last, T* smallest) -> T* {
    if (first != last) {
       if (*first < *smallest) {
         return loop( first + 1, last, first);
       } else {
         return loop( first + 1, last, smallest);
       }
    } else {
       return smallest;
    }
  };
  return loop(first + 1, last, first);
}
```

Is an improvement as it only assumes an `operator<(...)` but does not need to make assumptions about the "smallest possible value of T". It also shows more clearly how the "state" of the recursion is passed along (and thus makes this implementation tail recursive). And if lucky, the c++ compiler has an optimization for that and avoids unnecessary stack usage.

The next level of improvement would be to add an extra argument, which allows passing a compare function to `smallest`. And because we then as well could pass a "greater than" to this function, we could try and find a more general name.

```
template <class T>
T* selectLast( const T* first, const T* last, bool (*predicate)(const T*, const T*)) {
// ...
}
```

or

```
template <class T, class Pred>
T* selectLast( const T* first, const T* last, Pred predicate) {
// ...
}
```

Or we could generalize even more (since we are already in the realm of higher functions) and just offer a reduce/fold function. And as such a function already exists, we would use `std::reduce()` from the C++ standard library header file `<numeric>`.